# Function with multiple names

Tags: dart

In JavaScript you can do this to assign a function to multiple references:

```dart
z = function(){
  console.log(1)
}

x = y = z
```

Now when we call `x` or `y`, `1` gets printed to the `console`.

Is this possible in dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just like in JavaScript, functions are first class citizens and can be assigned to variables.

Also see this somewhat older, but still relevant video [Functions are Fun, Pt2](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-tips/dart-tips-ep-7.html).

As Example from the video:

```dart
loudPrint(String msg) {
  print(msg.toUpperCase());
}

var loudify = loudPrint;

loudify('Dart is fun');
  // DART IS FUN
```